# Procedure and function. Return one big string

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i, procedure

I writing this procedure and I have question how can I overwrite old value on new Value and return the new line with new big one string with new mails.
Procedure split one big email which have got emails on few single mails and change domain.

**Perception: I got one table with atributes example Values which have one big string with emails. I must change this emails to domain NewDomain.pl when its diffrent from aaa.pl and bbb.pl when its the same I leave this emails. example:**

**Old Value: 'zamowienia@kicius.pl mickey.mouse@aaa.pl kimus.walus@domek.pl'**

**and result I want update: 
**New Value:  'zamowienia@NewDomain.pl mickey.mouse@aaa.pl kimus.walus@NewDomain.pl'**

First procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE changeMailAll
AS             
BEGIN
       DECLARE  delim char(3); 
                cur_position INTEGER(11) DEFAULT 1;
                r_remainder VARCHAR(250);
                cur_string VARCHAR(1000);
                delim_length INTEGER;
                length_remainder INTEGER;
                mail VARCHAR(255);
                MAILs VARCHAR(20000);
                v_value VARCHAR2(255);
                v_valueNew VARCHAR2(255);
                v_customerId VARCHAR(20);
                c INTEGER;
                d INTEGER;
                positionMonkey INTEGER;
                v_identity VARCHAR(50);
                domena VARCHAR2(50);
                v_loop VARCHAR(100);
                adres VARCHAR(255);
                **str PKT_StringFnc.t_array;**

        CURSOR cursorMails IS
             SELECT Customer_Id, Value FROM PKT_userTrue where method_id = 'E_MAIL';  


     BEGIN

               OPEN cursorMails;

                   LOOP

                        FETCH cursorMails INTO v_customerId, v_value;

                              **str :=  PKT_StringFnc.SPLIT(v_value,' ');

                         FOR i IN 1..str.COUNT LOOP
                                 dbms_output.put_line('XXX1' || str(i));
                              END LOOP;**          
                   EXIT WHEN cursorMails%NOTFOUND;
                   END LOOP;
               CLOSE cursorMails;
END;
END;
```

End Second procedure where I split mail from first procedure

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKT_StringFnc
IS

   FUNCTION SPLIT (p_in_string VARCHAR2, p_delim VARCHAR2) RETURN t_array 
   IS

      i       number :=0;
      pos     number :=0;
      lv_str  varchar2(255) := p_in_string;
      positionMonkey INTEGER;
      domena VARCHAR2(50);
      adres VARCHAR(255);
      lv_str_new VARCHAR2(255);
      aaa VARCHAR(20) := '@aaa.pl ';
      bbb VARCHAR(30) := '@bbb.pl ';
      result VARCHAR(1000);


   strings t_array;

   BEGIN

      pos := instr(lv_str,p_delim,1,1);

      WHILE ( pos != 0) LOOP

         i := i + 1;
         strings(i) := substr(lv_str,1,pos);
         positionMonkey := INSTR(strings(i),'@');

         domena := SUBSTR(strings(i), positionMonkey);

         adres := RTRIM(strings(i),domena);

         lv_str := substr(lv_str,pos+1,length(lv_str));

         pos := instr(lv_str,p_delim,1,1);

         IF pos = 0 THEN
            strings(i+1) := lv_str;
                ELSE
                    strings(i+1) := lv_str_new;

         END IF;

          IF domena = aaa OR domena = bbb THEN

             lv_str_new := REPLACE(strings(i),domena,'@NewDomain.com');

           END IF; 
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lv_str_newREPLACE:'|| lv_str_new); 

      END LOOP;

      RETURN strings;
   END SPLIT;

END;
/
```

When I return one big string I want update in table and where I can do it ?

Thanks for help

Maybe somebody can rewrite easiest procedure from two to one procedure

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if something like

```
UPDATE pktTrue
SET Value = REGEXP_REPLACE(Value, '(@aaa.pl)|(@bbb.pl)|(@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})', '\1\2@NewDomain.pl', 1, 0, 'c')
WHERE method_id = 'E_MAIL';
```

will work for you?

Comment: mayebe its OK but it doesnt work. I use oracle 9i and I cant install another version.I understand this code is insetad of my function and procedure yes ? If I right your code its great.
Error: "ORA-00904: "REGEXP_REPLACE": niepoprawny identyfikator"

Comment: ok I add function regexp_replace from page http://phil-sqltips.blogspot.com/2009/06/regexpreplace-regexplike-for-oracle-9i.html AND its work but not OK. This update dont change a domain

Comment: Match the previous sub-expression between 2 and 4 times (ie top-level domain which is between 2 and 4 characters, currently).

Comment: I'm not sure if owa_pattern.change supports the back references needed in the "replacement" argument.